# Viewing Reports without ReportViewer Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

Having a JS web application (ASP.NET MVC, talking via REST with the server) I cannot use the server-side ReportViewer Control to open reports generated by the Microsoft Reporting Services.

I am searching for ways to open reports without making the Reporting Services public. It is no option to pregenerate the reports and just linking them.

My first idea was setting a route to a server-side controller that creates a web request (calling Reporting Services with all necessary parameters), caches the response and returns it to the client. But I am not sure if this will be the best solutions.

Does anybody had the same task and might share his/her solution?

Thank you! 
Oskar

Comment: As I found out (via resources á la [link](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=1009061&page=1)) it's the best way to create an ASPX having the ReportViewer control inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, reports may have subreports, which have to load data from the server it's the best choice to use the ReportViewer Control. So the solution is to create an plain old Web Forms APSX having this control included until there will be an updated/new control from Microsoft. This works pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

With no postbacks `ReportExecution2005.Render` will be your friend. Drop the report viewer and create a scheme that works for you:) Telerik controls just released a MVC viewer control but.

Already, I implemented a BaseReportController in conjunction with a BaseReportModel in conjunction with a BaseReportView that includes paging, exporting, refreshing etc. etc.

Pain in the ass...please let me know when there is something better.

Comment: Another option would be to include a folder in you mvc project that contains forms and place your report viewer in there and allow forms to be processed in your app. However, this will fire up both the .net mvc and .net forms processing when you app loads.